# Are there any API wrapper of Robocopy?

Tags: .net, windows, api, robocopy

Robocopy is the best reliable and feature rich way to batch copy files on Windows. However, it is a command line tool.

I am looking for a library/API that I could do the same in my program. I tried to use Process.Start(), but then I have to capture and to parse stdout for progress bar and no way to the overwrite behavior.

For example, exclude file base on delegate function; rename file if it is older; (re)start copy based on some events.

I guess copy, xcopy, recursive copy and etc, should be the most frequency wheel programmers do reinvent. Are there any API/library I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, and after some more research, I believe the API does not exist.

The maximum degree of reusing the feature from Robocopy is fork a child process with command line arguments.

Answer (score 12):

I realize that this is a very old post, but just in case someone stumbles upon it...

I wrote a wrapper for robocopy in c# called RoboSharp. It does exactly what the OP originally requested.

https://github.com/tjscience/RoboSharp

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some stuff out there which puts a GUI on it, e.g. [Synchronizing Images and Files in Windows Vista and XP Using Microsoft SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=50FA5932-0685-4FE3-9605-536F39BD6C86&displaylang=en) (forum [here](http://forums.microsoft.com/sync/ShowForum.aspx?ForumID=2026&SiteID=75)) and [Utility Spotlight - Robocopy GUI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc160891.aspx). I haven't found an API as yet, nor whether Robocopy exposes ActiveX-style control.

*Edit*: The rather large online description of [Robocopy](http://www.ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) says something about

> Robocopy 'Jobs' and the 'MOnitor source' option provide an alternative to setting up a Scheduled Task to run a batchfile with a RoboCopy command.

Might help. Might not.